# Clear up AjaxToolkit AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using an AsyncFileUpload control in my aspx.net page. This control is running inside an update panel.

I can successfully upload files to the server asynchronously.

My problem is that I can't refresh the entire page after each file is uploaded, so I need to figure out how to clear up the last uploaded file, so when the user selects a new file to upload, the old file does not appear in the control and the control does not keep its last upload in ViewState.

I have tried this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Clear-contents-of-AsyncFileUpload-Control-after-upload-and-page-revisit.aspx but it only clears up the html, when I do the server async postback, the AsyncFileUpload control still has the last file uploaded.

Is there a way to do the clean up at server side? Perhaps anything related to view state?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

On the client side you can use `OnClientUploadComplete` event to clear up the last uploaded file entry. Once the file uploading is completed and when the postback occurs the `AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile` will return `false`.

In `aspx` page:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="success" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" runat="server" />
```

and inside JavaScript tags:

```
function success() {         
    var fu = document.getElementById("AsyncFileUpload1"); 
    document.getElementById("AsyncFileUpload1").innerHTML = fu.innerHTML; 
}
```

Comment: `function success(sender, args) { $(sender._element).find('input').val(''); }`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
function ClearFile() {
    $('input[type="file"]').each(function () {
        $("#" + this.id).replaceWith($("#" + this.id).clone(true));
    });

    //For other browsers
    $('input[type="file"]').each(function () { $("#" + this.id).val(""); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side clearing worked for me :

```
protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
    AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") + filename);

    ClearContents(sender as Control);
}

private void ClearContents(Control control)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < Session.Keys.Count; i++)
   {
      if (Session.Keys[i].Contains(control.ClientID))
      {
         Session.Remove(Session.Keys[i]);
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

reference: link in the question by Fer. 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Clear-contents-of-AsyncFileUpload-Control-after-upload-and-page-revisit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="success" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" runat="server" />
```

and

```
function success(sender, args) { $(sender._element).find('input').val(''); }
```

that one works perfectl on all modern browsers, thanks to "[Scotty.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123275/scotty-net)"